# Usb modem network disconnects and when I reconnect I have no internet access

Tags: networking, 16.04, internet, usb-modem

My ZTE USB modem disconnects after a certain period of time and when I reconnect it connects well but doesn't give internet access. I started noticing this after a certain update Ubuntu asked me to install, which I did, without seeing any errors.

The only way for me to regain internet access is to restart/reboot Ubuntu and then connect again to the Internet.

It works that way but the process is tedious and most of the time I'm in the middle of some work and when I lose connection I always have to restart my computer. I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. Is there a fix for this?

Comment: I have same problem. I don't reboot the OS whenever modem is connected but doesn't give internet access. I just unplug my USB modem and then plug-in. My recommendation to fix this problem is upgrading Ubuntu packages. I upgraded some packages and this problem fixed. I don't need to unplug my modem when modem is disconnected. I just reconnect it.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for solution of similar problem. My usb 3G modem was disconnecting and connecting all over again and again, sometimes successfully, sometimes not. Working on Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS, but had the same issue on 18.04.

Solution in my case was to change IOMMU settings in UEFI bios to "disabled". This is specific to UEFI bios motherboard types as far as I know.

My motherboard: Gigabyte 970A-DS3P.

Also, I use Modem Manager GUI to control usb modem connection.

Modem:

- HSDPA USB Modem 29 
  (listed in GUI Manager)
- Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd. E161/E169/E620/E800 HSDPA Modem
   (listed
  by running `lsusb` in bash terminal).